# CUPS - Remove Password Prompt

Tags: 12.04, server, printing

I have a printer installed on an ubuntu server (12.04 LTS)

I can print items with no issue, but it always prompts for a username and password, which is super annoying.

I tried everything I could find about it online but nothing seems to remove the prompt.

I set DefaultAuthType to None in  /etc/cups/cupsd.conf, still a prompt.

also just read this post:

[Cups is always asking for password when printing on a certain printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164111/cups-is-always-asking-for-password-when-printing-on-a-certain-printer)

but that didn't help either sadly, though for me I only have one printer so I'm baffled on what to do now.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is what my CUPS files look like:

printer.conf

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.5.3  
# Written by cupsd    # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter Canon_MX310_series>
UUID urn:uuid:5a7453c6-3dc0-3bce-53f1-7584efb6144a
Info Canon MX310 series
Location Living Rm
MakeModel Canon PIXMA MX300 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.8-pre1
DeviceURI usb://Canon/MX310%20series?serial=16BE66&interface=1
State Idle
StateTime 1388353343
Type 12627980
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
AuthInfoRequired none
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Option media-col media-bottom-margin
</Printer>
```

cupsd.conf

```
LogLevel warn
MaxLogSize 0
SystemGroup lpadmin
# Allow remote access
Port 631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
Browsing On
BrowseOrder allow,deny
BrowseAllow all
BrowseLocalProtocols CUPS dnssd
BrowseAddress @LOCAL
DefaultAuthType None
WebInterface Yes
<Location />
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin>
  AuthType None
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType None
  Require user @SYSTEM
  # Allow remote access to the configuration files...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Policy default>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny, allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
<Policy authenticated>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType None
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny, allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change in `/etc/cups/printers.conf`

```
AuthInfoRequired none
```

I have installed  hp2015 and don't have problem

```
<DefaultPrinter hp2015>
UUID urn:uuid:c7c39f9e-7dc7-3a45-7531-fc4222d08420
AuthInfoRequired none
Info hp2015
Location x.x.x.x
MakeModel HP LaserJet p2015 Series pcl3, hpcups 3.13.9
DeviceURI ipp://x.x.x.x:631/printers/hp2015
State Idle
StateTime 1393930474
Type 8425502
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Option cups-browsed true
</Printer>
```

and this is my `cupsd.conf`

```
LogLevel warn MaxLogSize 0
# Allow remote access Port 631 Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
# Share local printers on the local network. Browsing On BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd DefaultAuthType Basic WebInterface Yes
<Location />   # Allow shared printing...   Order allow,deny   Allow
all </Location> <Location /admin> </Location> <Location /admin/conf>  
AuthType Default   Require user @SYSTEM </Location> <Policy default>  
JobPrivateAccess default   JobPrivateValues default  
SubscriptionPrivateAccess default   SubscriptionPrivateValues default 
<Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes
Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription
Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job
Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class
CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job
Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer
Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer
Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs
CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow   </Limit> </Policy> <Policy authenticated>   JobPrivateAccess default   JobPrivateValues default  
SubscriptionPrivateAccess default   SubscriptionPrivateValues default 
<Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes
Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription
Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job
Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class
CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job
Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer
Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer
Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs
CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow   </Limit>   <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow   </Limit> </Policy>
```

You can check your part of /etc/cups/printers.conf and `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.
I don't have problem with authorization when printing.

Comment: AuthInfoRequired isn't on there, so I'll try to add that tonight when I have access to my server (its a home server so its not publicly broadcasted) and see if that does it.

Comment: that didnt work either, I altered my question to include what my config files look like.

Comment: Try to replase your cups.conf with my. Restart cups and try to print.

Comment: Could you correct your line breaks?